# Can't see homepage when not logged in with ACL CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, acl

When I am not logged in and I'm viewing my homepage (localhost) then I'm automatically getting redirected to the login page.
Is this normal? And what can I do about it..

Answer (score 1):

Your home page probably isn't set as public. In your controller's `beforeFilter()` you can set it as such. For example:

```
$this->Auth->allow('index');
```

will make your `index` action viewable to all users, whether or not they're logged in.